# How to change TextAlign of the From/To field in outlook custom form?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

When i am creating the ***From*/*To*** field from Field Chooser, there is no property to text alignment.

I tried to change with vba in  `Function Item_Open()` :

```
Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Message").Controls("From").TextAlign = 3
```

but I failed. An Error that there is no such property as the *TextAlign*

I tried to do the mapping of the sender and the recipient through labels, but when i do double-click on the label, there does not display information about the sender/recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such property for standard controls. Instead, consider developing an add-in with a form region where you can use any controls. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) for more information. For example, you may use the *Replacement* layout which adds the form region as a new page that replaces the default page of an Outlook form. Or the *Replace-All* one which replaces the whole Outlook form with the form region.

Comment: There is no _Form Regions_ in  outlook 2003. I am using opportunities of outlook 2003  in order to support backward compatibility.